# SharePoint Total Page View count and the Popularity Trends View Count mismatched

Tags: sharepoint-server, analytics

Currently in our production environment for some pages the total page view and the Popularity Trends generated Excel view count are not matching.

Below is an Example.

For this page total view is **3910** but when I generate Popularity Trends for this page the total no of view count is different (**3894**).
[image]

Here you can see the total count is **3894**

[image]

Could you please suggest me how to debug this or what are the steps I need to follow to fix this. I have completely no idea from where to start debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is based on a feature called **TailTrimming** parameter. TailTrimming determines when the usage analytics *reports* should be updated. By default, the reports are updated when the item is updated at least *3* times within the *last 24 hours*. This is designed to balance the load usage of your SharePoint system, as low usage items aren't getting new reports as frequently as commonly accesses items.

However, the value you see with the page's popup is not based on the TailTrimming affected property. The number of views you see in the page's pop-up window is based on the property `ViewsLifeTime` which is updated by SharePoint Usage Analytics every 15 days.

As a bottomline we can conclude, that the view counts are intended to work like this. In the last hand, you should rely on the reports, but understand that they also have a range of 0-2 accuracy when your default TailTrimming property value is used. If this is a business crucial value to track, you can change the default value with the following PowerShell:

> ```
> $SSP = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplicationProxy
> $tenantConfig = $SSP.GetAnalyticsTenantConfiguration([Guid]::Empty)
> $event = $tenantConfig.EventTypeDefinitions | where-object { $_.EventTypeId -eq <EventTypeId> }
> $event.TailTrimming = <TailTrimming>
> $tenantConfig.Update($SSP)
> ```
>
> Where  is the numeric [EventTypeId](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2014/01/16/an-introduction-to-recommendations-and-popular-items-in-sharepoint-server-2013.aspx#DefaultUsageEvents) of the usage event that you want to change, and  is the minimum amount of times the usage event has to occur within 24 hours for the usage analytics reports to be updated.

References:

- [View and configure usage analytics reports in SharePoint Server
  2013](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/2014/01/23/view-and-configure-usage-analytics-reports-in-sharepoint-server-2013/)
- [ViewLifeTime Managed Property not getting updated.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/fdc5c56e-b3ec-4006-8fc6-d593b6ec028d/viewlifetime-managed-property-not-getting-updated?forum=sharepointsearch)

Comment: Thanks Moe for you quick response, i got a small doubt, in our environment there are more than 500 pages and during my investigation i almost checked each and every page, out of that only few pages are having this mismatch issue,so just curious to know why some pages are only affected by this and under which scenario this happens.

Comment: @SouravKumar The functionality is the same for all, but the TrailTrimming property is item-specific, so the values may or may not differ mostly depending on their popularity. If I were you, I'd keep on eye on a few popular items and see how their values are getting updated e.g. daily. If there seems to be an odd pattern, there might be a need for further investigations.