# SharePoint 2013 News Page View Count Mismatch

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-search

We have a publishing site where we publish News from our organization, and the article will be viewed by the end users and the article will either be given "Like" or "Comments" from the user.

We could notice that there is mismatch between the Published News Page View Count. For some of the Pages the View Count is showing in lesser count and for some of the pages it showing Larger count.

I also checked in "Pages" library for that site collection, I Could see the same Wrong View count there also.

I tried to check the Search Crawl logs, but i could not notice that specific URL over there.

Could any of you please help me out on this regard, It is highly business critical. Your Help will be highly appreciated!!

Note: Publishing template "CMSPUBLISHING#0 is used for the page. We have "HarePoint analytics which gives the view count different from that of the Page views count.

Thanks,

Raj

Answer (score 0):

The Page views count updates based on the “ViewsLifeTime” parameter, which is different from view count in the usage report. These parameters are updated in different time that might cause your scenario.

More information check the similar post: [SharePoint Total Page View count and the Popularity Trends View Count mismatched](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/220659/sharepoint-total-page-view-count-and-the-popularity-trends-view-count-mismatched)